How can I test Li-ion battery?
I have xiaomi robot vaccum cleaner which doesn't work at all.It seems that If I docked it  with my own hands It is possible to charge robot vaccum cleaner But It seems that It suddenly discontinue to charge and If I undocked it It is impossible to power on...
So I doubt its Li-iron battery has been broken or not.
below picture is a Li-ion battery which I want to check it.
How can I test Li-ion battery?
How can I test Li-ion battery whether it have been broken or not?

What tools you have or how much you can spend to build an electronics lab where testing of lithium batteries is possible?

Is it impossible to measure voltage of  lithium batteries with multimeter?

You can measure the voltage but that won't tell you whether it's the battery or the charging circuits that are faulty.

This lithium batteries has 4 pin(red,white,blue,black) connector. what pin should I measure with DMM? https://i.ibb.co/WpLFKXS/IMG-20241014-183821.jpg
